# line-height 2px lower in firefox vs webkit

Tags: firefox, webkit, css

I have the following css:

```
.btn_container {
cursor: pointer;
font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Arial;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}

.btn_center {
background: blue;
color: #FFFFFF !important;
display: block;
float: left;
font-weight: bold;
height: 32px;
line-height: 32px;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

*line-height of 30 lines up center in firefox, but 32 in webkit.*

I know browsers will render things differently, but i've never had a problem getting text to center properly.

In the following example you can see that it drops a couple px lower in firefox:
http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/EGzEB/5/

Comment: are you using a CSS reset stylesheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've done heavy testing of this in the past. I call it *text jiggle*. It's not something you can control. All you can do to minimize it is apply an explicit line-height (especially one in px) to every text element.

The default line-height varies by a wide margin in different browsers, and for different font families at different font sizes. Setting an explicit line-height addresses that.

But within that, the exact placement of the text within the line-height space will vary slightly browser-to-browser no matter what you do. For some combinations of font-size and line-height, all browsers match up. For instance, Arial at `font-size:11px` and `line-height:14px` renders the same in FF, Webkit, and IE. But change the line-height to 13px or 15px, and it varies by 1px browser-to-browser.

There's no standard or defined behavior for it. It's the result of how that particular font-family, font-size, and line-height happens to be rendered by the browser on that operating system. Arial, for instance, is a relatively consistent font, generally not varying by more than 1px as long as an explicit line-height is defined, while Helvetica varies by as many as 4 to 6 pixels.

Comment: `font-family:Arial;font-size:11px;line-height:14px` doesn't render properly for me properly in Firefox on OSX.

Answer (score 10):

I had the opposite experience actually.  I noted that some header elements were positioned higher in IE7/compatibility mode as well as Chrome/Safari.  So after much trouble I inspected with chrome and saw -webkit-margin-before: 1.6em or something added to the headers. Adding that value and tweaking it didn't work because it effected the height of the header which pushed some elements down but the padding option worked well for me ...

I found that this worked for me:

```
H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, a.mainTab div {
  -webkit-padding-before: 1px;
}
```

a.mainTab div had spans which wouldn't respond to the padding/margin so wrapped them in a div ... this may work for li span span headers as well.

Comment: This works perfectly and just does what is needed!