# Positioning of text in input tag & buttons. line-height is flat-out ignored sometimes

Tags: html, font-size, css

I can't get my some of my buttons or inputs to look the same across browsers. The vertical positioning of text is usually the problem. I've tried multiple browsers, Firefox (16) simply ignores my line-height in OSX and looks different still in Windows.

There's usually a difference of 1px, sometimes more. This is especially a problem when you switch to an iPad or another mobile device, it always looks different somehow.
Here's my CSS...

```
  margin         : 0px;
  padding        : 0px;
  font-size      : 15px;
  //height       : 15px; // Tried this too with unsatisfying results
  line-height    : 1;
  vertical-align : top;
```

I took the screenshots without using the height-property
[image: line-height problem in browsers chrome, safari, ie10, firefox. in osx & windows 8]

*edit:*
so I've looked around for more information and found some questions with a similar problem.
No one solved it though...
-> [1 pixel line height difference between Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439537/1-pixel-line-height-difference-between-firefox-and-chrome)
-> [line-height 2px lower in firefox vs webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762267/line-height-2px-lower-in-firefox-vs-webkit)

*edit2:*
furthermore if I make a jsfiddle I still get the problem, it's a little different since it's not in the same context as on the site I'm working on but it's still a line-height/text issue:
see here: http://jsfiddle.net/XQ7VD/3/
This is Chrome (left) and Firefox (right) on OSX

*edit3:*
Here's a screenshot with the line-height set to 18px (from this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJ8eR)
[image]

I've just seen that the jsfiddle buttons and hover-boxes have the same issue! xD
Ok I'm done screenshooting now...

--
If anyone does know a trick, please get in touch. thx!

Comment: Please create a fiddle so we can take a look at your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Text rendering is different in all browsers on various platforms - font antialiasing is absolutely different. So it is hard to get pixel-perfect results. From my experience, styling input/buttons elements for a large set of browsers is a major PITA. Especially mobile Webkit is unpredictable in certain cases.

If your CSS is not an excerpt, you may want to add `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: I've tried this just now but sadly it didn't solve the problem.
I made a jsfiddle and still have a similar issue with the positioning, I've updated my question with the jsfiddle link.

Comment: @Yoschi Strange `line-height:1` (without dimensions). I've set it to 18px: http://jsfiddle.net/BJ8eR/
I don't have a Mac to test it, please try this fiddle.
I've tried it on Win7 FF and Chrome, and with `line-height:1` height was different, while with `line-height:18px` it was equal.

Comment: I've made screenshots with lots of browsers of your fiddle in both osx and win8 and added them to my question :) issue still there though