# Different text align behavior for firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

[image: Firefox 38, Safari, Chrome]

It just a simple as

```css
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size:34pt;">BRIDGES YEAH</div>
```

Safari and Chrome are ok. But what wrong with a Firefox ? Is it different default value for something or what ?

Comment: Probably the browser's in-built stylesheets.

Comment: normalize css doesn't help

Comment: Have you set margin/padding on the element containing "bridges"? Whatever that element is it might have different default styles accross browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to predict browser behaviours. A closer solution is to use a line-height.

```
div{
    line-height:1;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/js23fefm/1/

Comment: They are still different, but it is a closer i had. Thanks.

Comment: It become a same when I set a different font. ( Open Sans Condensed ) 
And it looks different with few other fonts.

Firefox and Chrome are differs almost at half glyph when I set this font. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Bebas 

I guess FF works different with glyph, may it doesn't count ( or count in different way ) some font metrics....

Comment: Yes, like I said, its hard to predict. Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762267/line-height-2px-lower-in-firefox-vs-webkit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a normalize CSS file. There are a few out there, I use [this](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.2/normalize.css). It should make the way browsers render things more consistent.