# How to make text on webpage stay consistent relative to each other/navigation bar at different resolutions?

Tags: html, css

total novice here.
I've been working on my first real website for a couple of days, and have hit a bit of a snag in one particular area: I can't seem to get it to look consistent across all resolutions. I am aware that certain things are more difficult than others to keep consistent across multiple platforms, but this particular aspect must be the same relative to the navigation bar and the background picture.

I've tried changing position types, using px instead of pt, font sizes, line sizes, and none of them seemed to work- they'd look perfect on one resolution, but on another they would overlap with each other or be too close/too far from the navigation bar.

CSS:

```css
 @font-face { font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO"; src: url('ADAM.CGPRO.otf'); } 
 @font-face { font-family: "Raleway"; src: url('RALEWAY-BOLD.TTF'); } 
 @font-face { font-family: "Raleway Light"; src: url('RALEWAY-REGULAR.TTF'); } 
html, body {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 line-height: 100%;
}
.bgImageP {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.36;
}
.bgImageM {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#header {
 margin-top: 25px;
 text-align: center;
  font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO";
 font-size: 60pt;
 color: #BEBEBE;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
 display: none;
 width: 100;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#header2 {
 margin-top: 25px;
 text-align: center;
  font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO";
 font-size: 60pt;
 color: #9b9b9b;
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0; 
}

#subheading {
 margin-top: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "ADAM.CG PRO";
 font-size: 14pt;
 color: #800000;
 text-shadow: 1px 0.5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#cssmenu {
  background: #7a0000;
  width: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px grey;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #BEBEBE;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #BEBEBE;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #BEBEBE;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
.redButton {
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0px;
 text-shadow: 0px 3px 4px #666666;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #666666;
 font-family: Raleway Light;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 22px;
 background: #8a0000;
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
 display: none;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
.redButton:hover {
 background: #424242;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title>Bob Smith</title>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fader").fadeIn(1500);
});
$(function() {
  var src = '/img/matdesign1.png';
  var ele = $('.bgImageM');
  var img = $('<img>', {
    src: src
  }).hide().appendTo(ele).load(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    ele.css('background-image', 'url('+src+')').fadeIn(2500);
  });
});    
</script>
<body>
<nav>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='/index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='/resume/index.html'><span>Resume</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='/about.html'><span>About</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="bgImageM"></div>
<div id="header" class="fader">Bob Smith</div>
<div id="subheading" class="fader">Professional human being</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pictures:**

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwKeU.png)

[How it looks on a slightly smaller display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byyUw.jpg)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Grids may are the solution: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thought this [S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762267/line-height-2px-lower-in-firefox-vs-webkit) explained it well. 2 perspectives. The second one is most interesting. Hope that helps.

```
H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, a.mainTab div {
    -webkit-padding-before: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whup, fixed it. Turns out the font I was using just had screwy line heights. My bad.